# Scale up/zoom 980px wide webpages to occupy full width on tablets/small screen devices

Tags: android, html, css, tablet

I designed my webpages for 980px screen width resolutions. On tablets/small screen devices, though the resolutions width is more than 980px but *(obviously)* things look  much smaller  & the pages don't yet occupy full width, so there is some scope for pages to look a bit bigger.

I want the webpages to scale up/zoom to occupy full available screen width in mobile devices/tablets.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the viewport meta tags at the top of your HTML?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2">
```

That will make your page display properly on mobile devices.

Also add in e.g.

```
.site { width: 100%; max-width: 980px }
@media all and (min-width: 981px)
{
  .site { max-width: 1200px; }
}
```

Where .site is changed to whatever you have.  This second part my cause other layout issues while the meta tag will scale things up a bit without layout issues.  But both are needed together for tablets/mobiles to display your css and HTML properly.

I didn't want to put max-width: 100%; in the CSS above as you may come across some very wide browsers which would completely break your layout.  It's always best to find the maximum you want your design to stretch to e.g. 1200px.

Comment: is this(**using viewport metatags**) a cross-browser & cross-device compatible solution ?

Comment: Yes.  All browsers and devices recognise this as far as I am aware. I haven't in any of my testing come across a device that doesn't.

Comment: Thanks Colin! very awesome! But I'm trying to use this with `minimum-scale=1` but it does not deliver expected results. I am able to scale down even below `1`. why `minimum-scale` does not work but `maximum-scale` works?

Comment: Also my way of doing it was to use zoom property through javascript. I would calculate the zoom factor that is required to make the page occupy full width & dynamically set the zoom property for document body but unfortunately zoom property is not cross browser compatible & it dd not worked as expected.

Comment: Don't think there is a minimum scale. You can set width=980px and that'd scale up on tablets, and fill on mobiles. But it is not advised. You are heading into the world of responsive design and multiple devices :-) keep as is and use media queries to change widths of your outer container elements, what they may be.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting 'max-width:100%;' for things you want to extend to full screen for devices with screen larger than 980px:

```
@media (min-width: 980px){
  .your-class{
    max-width:100%;
  }
}
```